# I am trying to check if an email has a three letter extension such as ".com" or ".net" or not and this is not working

Tags: java

this is not working and I cannot figure out why

```
do {
    System.out.println("enter your work email");
    workEmail = scnr.nextLine();
    if (workEmail.substring(workEmail.length() - 4) != ".") {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid email. example: JohnDoe@yahoo.com");
    }

} while (workEmail.substring(workEmail.length() - 4) != ".");
```

Comment: it would not post correctly so it looks weird.

Comment: `workEmail.endsWith(".com")`

Comment: `workEmail.substring(workEmail.length() - 4)` will return a String that you have to compare for equality using equals: e.G. `if(workEmail.substring(workEmail.length() - 4).equals(".com"))`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has two main issues:

1. You should never compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use `.equals()` or even better `StringUtils.equals()`.
2. You're using `subString()`, when you want to use `charAt()`. While chatAr would work, the solution from @YCF_L s comment using `.endWith()` is way superior.

Comment: it works if I use c# and -4, 1 but I cannot figure out what is different in java

Comment: It might work in C# and not in Java maybe because C# and java are in fact different programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

This line is possibly incorrect;

```
workEmail.substring(workEmail.length() - 4) != "."
```

This will fail if the email address is, for instance "johndoe@site.se"

If you really want to make sure that it ends with ".com", you could write something like this:

```
String dotcom = ".com";    
if (workEmail.endsWith(dotcom) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
!workEmail.substring(workEmail.length() - 4).contains(".")
```

inside your if condition and while loop